# Is it possible to backup empty folders with Windows 10 File History?

Tags: windows, windows-10, backup, file-history

Does anyone know whether it is possible to backup empty folders with Windows 10 File History?

It seems not to do so by default and I have not been able to find any sort of switch for it in the File History controls.

Surely, empty folders may be a crucial part of data structures you want to recreate when restoring from backup.

Comment: (1) The fact that you expressed an opinion in your question is not the reason why it was put on hold (although our [Code of Conduct](/conduct) discourages the use of words like “stupid”). Your question was put on hold because it asked ***why*** a piece of software was designed the way it was. Yes, if a Microsoft employee is a member of our community, they might be able to give a historical account of the decision-making process. But most of us would only be able to guess at the developer’s reasons; i.e., we would be offering *our* opinions.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) While your edit transformed the question to one that can be answered objectively, it looked like you were asking a question that you already knew the answer to.  I tweaked it to focus on what you really *want* to know, as expressed in the last paragraph. (3) As it stands now, the question is somewhat verbose, saying things two and three times.  I didn’t want to delete anything you wrote, no matter how redundant.  I encourage you to [edit] it again, getting to the point more economically.  You might want to move the “real question” earlier in the question body.

Comment: Thank you, I take all your points. I have moved the last para "real question" to the top, as you suggested, cut the last paragraph (superfluous) and given the heading of "Background" for the three remaining paras explaining how I came to the question.

Comment: I have pruned some more, trying for succinctness. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed this behavior, and can assure you that this is by design. You see. File History was designed to backup documents, not data with custom schemas. AFAIK there are other schema types that File History will ignore completely, like some databases, that it thinks are used for things like outlook folder structures that will simply be re-downloaded, and frequently updated.

That being said. If you want to capture those folders, simply drop an empty text document in those folders, and File History will back them up.